# jqDock and PNG images with transparent background

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, png

I'm trying to use a jqDock library, but it refuses to work with transparent png images. Is there any tweek to make it work properly.
Thanx in advance.

Answer (score 0):

jqDock does not "refuse" to work with transparent images : it has no concept of what "transparent" means. So the answer is No, there is no "tweak" that will help. If the jqDock plugin is not working it is most likely a missing image, malformed or inappropriate HTML, or a script error ... all of which can be checked with the appropriate developer tools available in, or for, all modern browsers.